# Was heißt saumförmig?

Tags: meaning

Leider kann ich aus den vielen Gebrauchsbeispielen die Bedeutung von "saumförmig" nicht verstehen.

> Sklerosesaum bezeichnet eine radiologisch darstellbare saumförmige
>   Sklerose, die einen knöchernen Bereich umfasst, in dem eine
>   Veränderung der Kochenstruktur vorliegt.
>
> Die lange, saumförmige Rückenflosse wird bei vielen Arten nur von
>   Hartstrahlen gestützt.
>
> Die Ligula ist 2 bis 4 Millimeter lang und saumförmig.
>
> Bei beiden Gattungen ist die erste Rückenflosse hoch und wird vorn von
>   einem Stachel geschützt, die zweite Rückenflosse ist niedrig und
>   saumförmig langgestreckt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unter "Saum" ist ganz allgemein ein Rand zu verstehen. Der Begriff wird typischerweise unter anderem beim Nähen verwendet. Dort bezeichnet er eine Gewebekante, die meistens doppelt umgeschlagen und festgenäht wird, um ein Ausfransen zu verhindern. Das führt zu einem gleichmäßigem, schmalen Streifen, der dabei die Form dessen, was er umsäumt, annimmt. Diese Eigenschaft war vermutlich namensgebend für die aufgeführten Beispiele.

Comment: Das ist aber mal eine knackige, saubere Definition eines Saums!